# express - nodejs - Keep URL if in a subdomain instead of redirecting

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, vhosts

My current set up is such that `http://test.com/project` points to some root index view.

Using this [gist](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js), I have it so that `http://mysubdomain.test.com` redirects to the aforementioned url.

This is *okay*, but ideally I would like it such that the subdomain stayed in tact. I have not found a way to redirect while keeping the URL the same.

Answer (score 0):

redirect means go to another URL. there's no way to keep the original url. The only way to keep it is to map the subdomain on same route OR use parameter/regex in subdomain name. Express fully allows for that: app.get('/:subdomain.test.com/' or app.get(Regex(...)). this way the SAME callback is called in your code, you don't need to redirect and you serve all subdomains you want.

OR, use this https://www.npmjs.org/package/subdomain

Comment: So yeah... stupid me. I was actually just looking for nginx. The concept that there really is no "server" in Node threw me off.

Comment: I don't agree. In Nginx, you can do internal redirect, so that you request a file, if the file is not found, then it redirects it to your app route to generate that image, but the original url remains the same, as redirection is happening and handled internally.